# Can we use The Salesforce AJAX Toolkit in managed packages?

Tags: managed-package, ajax-toolkit

Can we use The Salesforce AJAX Toolkit in managed packages ?

Answer (score 4):

The AJAX Toolkit is simply a wrapper for the SOAP API. As such, you can use the AJAX Toolkit assuming the following holds true: your package has API access enabled, the user has API access enabled, and the organization has API access enabled. Given these three things, the AJAX Toolkit should work just fine in your clients' organizations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX toolkit but keep in mind that its gone consume the API's of your client's org .Since its a Javascript wrapper over SOAP API ,I would avoid using it unless absolutely have no other options .Explore Javascript remoting or Remote objects since they will not count towards API limits and they are very secure .